# How to use OpenCV cornerSubPix() in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, corner-detection, non-maximum-suppression

I'm trying to get and paint corner points in an image. Now, I have a list of tuples with the following format: `(row,column,scale)` (scale is because I'm using a Gaussian Pyramid), obtained from harrisCornerDetector and nonMaximumSupression process manually. This list is `featuresy1`.

My code is the following:

```
r,g,b=cv2.split(image)
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
cv2.cornerSubPix( r, featuresy1, (5,5), (-1,1), criteria )
```

Where image is an image in grayscale with three identical shapes. As you can see, I'm giving to `cornerSubPix` as second parameter a structure like this: `[(x1,y1,scale1),(x2,y2,scale2),...,(xn,yn,scalen)]`.

This is throwing the following error:

```
cv2.cornerSubPix( r, featuresy1, (5,5), (-1,1), criteria )
TypeError: corners is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

For this reason I wonder what type, format or structure should have `featuresy1` to do `cornerSubPix()` working. Is this the only thing I'm doing wrong? There isn't much documentation about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `corners` is numpy array with 3 dimensions `(n, 1, 2)`, where n is the number of corners. It also has to be a type float32.

Just type

```
corners.shape
```

to verify this.

Type in

```
corners.dtype
```

To check you are using float32.

To me is looks like your corners `featuresy1` is list where it should be a numpy array. Convert it first to a numpy array:

```
featuresy1 = np.array(featuresy1)
```

Opencv has an easy to [understand example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/calibrate.py) that might help you